# Can Azure Active Directory conditional access policy be used to allow requests from particular IP addresses?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-policy

We have application registered on Active Directory. We want to restrict access to the application by IP Addresses , I found conditional policy seems to be exact fit. But what I found in documentation is it can be used to restrict traffic from certain IP addresses and countries. Can this feature be used other way to allow requests from certain specified IP addresses only? Any requests coming from IP address not specified should be rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the 'Location' Condition in Access Control. For e.g. selecting 'Any location' causes a policy to be applied to all IP addresses, which means any address on the Internet. This setting is not limited to IP addresses you have configured as named location. When you select Any location, you can still 'exclude specific locations' from a policy. For example, you can apply a policy to all locations except trusted locations to set the scope to all locations, except the corporate network. This way you can effectively allow requests from a particular IP address/Location and block all others.

For more information, You can refer to [Location condition in policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/location-condition#location-condition-in-policy). You can also use Report-only mode  or What If tool to evaluate the impact of the policy before enforcement.

Comment: Thanks Nishant. So you mean I can choose to block from any location and exclude trusted locations. Also I believe this can be done at application level.

Comment: The application registered run as a background service or daemon without a signed-in user. The application is accessed through Oauth2.0 authentication , can application still controlled through conditional access policy.

Comment: The application registered to run as a background service or daemon without a signed-in user and is accessed from AWS cloud.

Comment: Hi Nishant - it appears conditional access works only for interactive users , we are using service principal to access the registered access and it doesn't go through conditional access.

Comment: Hello, @AravindBabuKonda Your findings are correct. Unfortunately, SPNs skip conditional access. there is no way to limit their usage in CA today. However, the team is already working on this feature (no ETA though) and I would request you to upvote the same here. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/37867180-restricting-access-of-azure-service-principals-u

Comment: Thanks Nishant for your time.